patroni cluster has no leader
I'm setting up a Patroni cluster and facing an issue where both nodes remain in the 'stopped' state, and the logs indicate that the system is waiting for a leader to bootstrap. Here is the output when I run patronictl -c /etc/postgres0.yml list:
Cluster: postgres (7366xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx) ---------+----+-----------+
| Member | Host | Role | State | TL | Lag in MB |
+-------------+----------------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
| postgresql0 | xxx.xxx.xx.57 | Replica | stopped | | unknown |
| postgresql1 | xxx.xxx.xx.129 | Replica | stopped | | unknown |
+-------------+----------------+---------+---------+----+-----------+

Log Entries:
[postgres@patroni01 ~]$ patroni /etc/postgres0.yml
2024-05-07 13:24:24,345 INFO: No PostgreSQL configuration items changed, nothing to reload.
2024-05-07 13:24:24,401 INFO: Lock owner: None; I am postgresql0
2024-05-07 13:24:24,404 INFO: waiting for leader to bootstrap
(repeated logs)
2024-05-07 13:25:04,405 INFO: waiting for leader to bootstrap

Configuration Details:

Patroni version: 3.3.0
PostgreSQL version: 15
Configuration file:

scope: postgres
namespace: /service/
name: postgresql0

restapi:
  listen: xxx.xxx.xx.57:8008
  connect_address: xxx.xxx.xx.57:8008

etcd:
  host: xxx.xxx.xx.155:2379

bootstrap:
  dcs:
    ttl: 30
    loop_wait: 10
    retry_timeout: 10
    maximum_lag_on_failover: 1048576
    postgresql:
      use_pg_rewind: true
      use_slots: true
      pg_hba:
      - host replication replicator 127.0.0.1/32 trust
      - host replication replicator xxx.xxx.xx.57/0 trust
      - host replication replicator xxx.xxx.xx.129/0 trust
      - host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
      parameters:
  initdb:
  - encoding: UTF8
  - data-checksums

postgresql:
  listen: xxx.xxx.xx.57:5432
  connect_address: xxx.xxx.xx.57:5432
  data_dir: /data/patroni
  pgpass: /tmp/pgpass0
  authentication:
    replication:
      username: replicator
      password: replicator
    superuser:
      username: postgres
      password: postgres
  parameters:
    unix_socket_directories: '..'
tags:
    noloadbalance: false
    clonefrom: false
    nosync: false
    nostream: false

Attempts to resolve the issue:

Checked the network connectivity between the nodes.
Ensured that all nodes are running with the correct permissions.
Reviewed configuration files for any obvious mistakes.

Additional Questions:

What might be causing the cluster to not elect a leader, resulting in all nodes showing as 'stopped'?
Are there specific settings in the configuration that should be checked or modified to resolve this?
How can I troubleshoot the bootstrap process for errors that prevent leader election?

Any insights or suggestions to troubleshoot or resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Please see the Postgres logs to see if it’s failing to start

@Ofirfr yes startup is failing, postgres is dead state

Then see why it is failing.

Also, was it ever working earlier? If so, what triggered it to stop working?

I want to find out why it's failing, but I can't check the logs because Postgres has never run before. I encountered this problem while configuring patroni and trying to run it for the first time

The issue can be solved by dropping all Patroni clusters from DCS (Make sure you backed up the data):

Stopping Patroni on all nodes.
Running the command patronictl -c /etc/postgres.yml remove .
After removing the cluster, try starting Patroni on each node again.

